# how to tell which ISP a public IP address belongs to?

Tags: isp

Is it possible to know which ISP a public IP address belongs to?  For example, if the company you work for has two ISPs and there is some kind of networking equipment in the computer room that routes traffic out the one ISP or the other ISP?

Comment: It feels like you're actually asking "which ISP will this equipment decide to send the packets to", which is a different thing? Could you expand a bit on your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to know which ISP a public IP address belongs to?

Yes. There are a number of online tools, but the one I normally use is [What Is My IP? - See your real public IP address - IPv4 - IPv6](https://www.whatismyip.com/)

When I run that on my internet connection the output (censored) is:

> [image]